# Shortest Path in a Trie

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path, trie

For a Data Structures project, I must find the shortest path between two words like "cat" and "dog but i'm only allowed to change one letter at a time. I'm trying to do it by implementing a trie, and can't seem to be able to implement a shortest path search.

cat -> cot -> cog -> dog

All the words will be of the same length and I am populating them from a dictionary file.
We must move from word to word. So the word in between must be a valid word.

I think it's not really possible using a trie, but anyone have any knowledge?

Comment: Note that the shortest past in the kind of trie you usually construct from a dictionary is not a good metric for similarity! E.g., "pear" and "bear" are quite similar, but will require going up all the way to the root and down again in a standard trie.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a [VP-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP-tree)  and the algorithm is called [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
A C implementation can be found here, the code is far too long to post as an answer:
[C VP-Tree](http://read.pudn.com/downloads150/sourcecode/math/650936/vptree.c__.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A better data structure for this kind of problem is graph. 
It's called word ladder and you can look it up here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_ladder.

Answer (score -1):

What you are seeking for is a simple BFS. Each word is a graph vertex, but there is even no need to build the graph, you can solve it using array of words:

```
words = {"cat", "dog", "dot", "cot"}
mark = {0, 0, 0, 0}
distance = {0, 0, 0, 0}
queue Q
start_word_index = 0; // words[0] -> "cat"
destination_word_index = 1; // words[1] -> "dog"
Q.push(start_word_index)
while(Q is not empty) {
    word_index = Q.pop()
    for each `words[j]` {
        if (difference between `words[word_index]` and `words[j]` is only 1 character) AND
           (`mark[j]` is not 1) {
            mark[j] = 1
            Q.push(j)
            distance[j] = distance[word_index] + 1
        }
    }
}

if mark[destination_word_index] is 0 {
    print "Not reachable"
} else {
    print "Distance is ", distance[destination_word_index]
}
```